# Have Button onClick function Parent Component when it triggers the modal component is in Child Component is to appear

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

when I Click the onClick the function in the parent component the state value needs to change in the child component ...

Parent Component:

```
<Button  onClick={handleFormat}>Next</Button>
```

Child Component:

```
function UploadLegal() {

  handleFormat(){
   setShow(true)
  }

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
   return(
  <Modal className="uploadModal" show={show}>
  ......design.......
  </Modal>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass both values and functions as props from the parent to the child, but not from the child to the parent.  Therefore you want to [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) up to the Parent Component.

```
function Parent() {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleFormat = () => {
    setShow(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleFormat}>Next</Button>
      <UploadLegal show={show} setShow={setShow}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

The child gets the state from props rather than storing it itself.

```
function UploadLegal({show, setShow}) {
   return(
    <Modal className="uploadModal" show={show}>
    ......design.......
    </Modal>
  )
}
```